# Why do EC2 T2 instances sometimes start with zero CPU Credits

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

Can anyone explain why when I launch a new T2.micro instance, it occasionally (perhaps 1 in 50) starts with a CPU credit balance of zero, instead of the 30 it is meant to have?

I've attached screenshots of the CPU credit balances from two machines I launched nearly simultaneously from an Autoscaling group.

[image: Normal startup - 30 credits initially]

[image: Abnormal startup - 0 credits]

It isn't a massive deal, but it is upsetting my monitoring system to see near-zero cpu credits!

Comment: Are you starting many T2 instances during the same 24h period? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits

Comment: Spot on, I'd never noticed that footnote before!  We launch ~6 instances every time someone pushes a code change, so we can easily exceed 100 in a busy day. Post as an answer and the kudos is all yours ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Amazon notes in their [documentation on T2 (burstable) instances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits) that while these instances normally have 30 CPU credits initially, there are limits to how this initial credit will be applied.

> - There are limits to how many T2 instances will launch or start with the initial CPU credit, which by default is set to 100 launches or
>     starts of any T2 instance per account, per 24-hour period, per region.
>     If you'd like to increase this limit, you can file a customer support
>     limit increase request by using the Amazon EC2 Instance Request Form.
>     If your account does not launch or start more than 100 T2 instances in
>     24 hours, this limit will not affect you.

Comment: Yes that's the issue I also ran into.
It's a ridiculous setting, it means you pay the full price and receive a tiny fraction of the usual worth.

Comment: @John Like the documentation states, you can file a ticket to get the limit raised. I would assume the limit exists to discourage people from large-scale automating using T2 instances for their initial CPU credit only.